# Ubuntu 12.10 Kernel Problem on HP Envy M6?

Tags: kernel

Im very new in Ubuntu. Recently bought a Laptop Hp m6:

- Intel i5
- 8gb RAM
- Intel Graphics HD 4000

I install Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits, worked perfectly fine, but when I did the first system update (updated kernel to 3.0.25 (generic), when I reboot didnt do it it got stuck in the blank purple screen, so I tried to boot form an older kernel 3.0.24 (generic) I think, and it works.

What could be the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it come up with any error messages?

Comment: no.. just the blank purple screen... neither recovery mode of the kernel works..

Comment: Ok... I'll try and think of something...

Comment: thaks a lot man...

Comment: That's alright!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try downloading Synaptic Packet Manager from the Ubuntu Software Center. Once you download it and open it, scroll down the list on the left and click the option that says kernel. You can then search down the list until you see the linux kernel labeled 3.0.25 and right click > mark for uninstall. Then click apply at the top of Synaptic.

After you do this, you will need to restart your machine. It will load your previous kernel version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But he can't get into his system!

Comment: He said he booted into his system using a previous kernel. Right?

Comment: thanks for the fast response... it worked... now how can i avoid upgrade the kernel... for that problem...:)

Comment: Use the gui update program and you can check/uncheck packages. Just make sure the kernel isn't checked to update. Here in a couple of months, 3 or so, the kernels usually work out and there are no more problems. So in 3 months or so you can try loading the new kernel and see if it works then.

Comment: @CodeTheUniverse I guess so...

Comment: ok.. thaks... see u soon